# Ubuntu installer detecting multiple Windows 7 loaders

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, multi-boot

I bought a new HP dv6 laptop with Windows 7 installed, a 750GB hard drive and 8GB RAM.

I wanted to dual boot and install Ubuntu 11.10. Following a known procedure I shrunk my partition and created 30GB (unallocated space). I inserted a bootable USB key but the GUI installer showed the following message:

> Ubuntu detected that there are multiple OS are installed on your device.

There were two options:

1. Erase the entire disk and install Ubuntu
2. Do something else

When I chose the second option, it did not detect the unallocated space that I had created. It also showed me this:

```
SDA1 Windows7 (loader)
SDA2 Windows7 (loader)
```

I don't know how it's detecting multiple loaders or why it's not finding unallocated space for installation.

I also tried to fix the problem by unallocating the space using GParted but nothing happened. I think the space I unallocated using Gparted is now not detected by Windows 7.

I also tried Wubi which gave an unknown error while installing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate You will have to perform a HP Recovery, then read this...http://superuser.com/questions/359414/how-to-make-a-drive-partition-and-install-windows-on-it-from-an-hp-install-disc

Comment: Windows 7 requires a 100MB reserved boot partition. Could this be what you are seeing? You did not provide the sizes.