# How to make a new partition in Windows 7 Basic?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

`Disk Management` allowed me to create unallocated space but I cannot create new partition on that unallocated space please advice.

Comment: Most probably you already have 4 primary partitions.
In that case refer this question:http://superuser.com/questions/416621/partitioning-laptop-with-4-primary-partitions

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying with Disk Management it will allow to shrink that volume, then you can create a partition on it. It will mark it as secondary partition though, not primary.

Shrinking the volume depends on system management – it only allows to shrink continuous memory.

- *Disk Management → Select Volume → Shrink Volume*
- Unallocated space appears if the system allows it.
- Select the unallocated space → Create/add a new volume.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. When giving answers, try to give precise step-by-step answers, as most of our audience asking questions do not know computers well enough to interpret quick remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I suggest using [easus partition manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm), a freeware partition manager. To partition a drive, just click C: OsDisc (what mine says), the [resize/move](http://puu.sh/KNmB) button at the top of the screen, and adjust the [scrollbar](http://puu.sh/KNnr) until you're at your preferred size. It won't let you partition used drive space, though.